# cannot start multiple mysql instance with mysqld_multi

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I'm newbie on mysql. And today I tried to run multiple mysql instance with mysqld_multi with mysql 5.7.13 on Ubuntu 16.

My problems is when I execute cmd "mysqld_multi start --no-log", instances are not running. And I don't know what the error is according to the error log in syslog.

this is output:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/run/mysqld# mysqld_multi start --no-log
mysqld_multi log file version 2.16; run: Wed Aug 24 05:07:23 2016

Starting MySQL servers
root@ubuntu:/var/run/mysqld# 2016-08-24T12:07:25.411476Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2016-08-24T12:07:25.413934Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2016-08-24T12:07:25.457022Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2016-08-24T12:07:25.464033Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2016-08-24T12:07:25.708791Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/mysql1
2016-08-24T12:07:25.707895Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/mysql7
2016-08-24T12:07:27.349043Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld7.pid ended
2016-08-24T12:07:27.360686Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid ended
```

Mysql servers are not running:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/run/mysqld# mysqld_multi report
Reporting MySQL servers
MySQL server from group: mysqld1 is not running
MySQL server from group: mysqld7 is not running
```

and this is the log in syslog:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/run/mysqld# tail -50 /var/log/syslog

Aug 24 05:07:25 ubuntu mysqld_safe: Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
Aug 24 05:07:25 ubuntu mysqld_safe: Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
Aug 24 05:07:25 ubuntu mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/mysql1
Aug 24 05:07:25 ubuntu mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/mysql/mysql7
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33826]: /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) starting as process 33826 ...
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33825]: /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) starting as process 33825 ...
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33826]: Aborting
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33826]: Binlog end
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33826]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33825]: Aborting
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33825]: Binlog end
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld[33825]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld7.pid ended
Aug 24 05:07:27 ubuntu mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid ended
```

Here is the content of /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = multi_admin
password   = multipass

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql

[mysqld1]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock
port        = 3307
datadir     = /data/mysql/mysql1
basedir     = /usr

[mysqld7]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld7.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld7.sock
port        = 3308
datadir     = /data/mysql/mysql7
basedir     = /usr
```

I think the permission is well:

```
root@ubuntu:/data/mysql# ll
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 4 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 24 01:06 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 23 23:48 ../
drwxr-xr-x 5 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 24 05:07 mysql1/
drwxr-xr-x 5 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 24 05:07 mysql7/
```

Permissions in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld are also modified:

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock w,
/var/lib/mysql1/ r,
/var/lib/mysql1/** rwk,
/var/log/mysql1/ r,
/var/log/mysql1/* rw,
/var/log/mysql1.log rw,
/var/log/mysql1.err rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock w,
/data/mysql/mysql1/** rwk,
/data/mysql/mysql1/ r,


/var/run/mysqld/mysqld7.pid rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld7.sock w,
/var/lib/mysql7/ r,
/var/lib/mysql7/** rwk,
/var/log/mysql7/ r,
/var/log/mysql7/* rw,
/var/log/mysql7.log rw,
/var/log/mysql7.err rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld7.pid rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld7.sock w,
/data/mysql/mysql7/** rwk,
/data/mysql/mysql7/ r,
```

Why can't the instance start please?